# Apply list function on same itertools._grouper object give different value

Tags: python, list

The code below:

```
from itertools import groupby
for key, group in groupby(sorted([1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3])): 
    print(list(group))
    print(list(group))
```

return:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[]
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[]
```

Why does the second  `print(list(group))` output an empty list instead of something same as the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `group` is an iterator that you can exhaust and you do so with your first `list(group)` call.

*You can think of them as guns. When they are created they are fully loaded; but there is no way to re-fire a fired bullet.* Your second `list(group)` call, does exactly that; tries to fire an empty gun.